# How can I insert data in mysql using jsp? How can I correct my code?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, java-7

It is a sign up page How can I insert data in mysql using register.jsp.My DB conn.jsp file, execute correctly.But my register.jsp file have an error, please correct it my point out where I'm wrong?

**register.jsp**

```
   <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
   <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"%>
   <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
   <%@page  import=" java.sql.SQLException" %>

   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@include file="db conn.jsp"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <%    
    String name=request.getParameter("first");
        String abc=request.getParameter("last");
         String cde=request.getParameter("user");
         String pass=request.getParameter("password");
          String confpass=request.getParameter("confirmpass");
         String emails=request.getParameter("email");
          String months=request.getParameter("month");
          String day=request.getParameter("day");
         String year=request.getParameter("year");
            String gender=request.getParameter("Gender");

     String Sql="insert into teacher2(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) values('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";

        rs=st.executeQuery(Sql);   

     %>
```

---

**db conn.jsp**

```
     <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
     <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"%>
     <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
     <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
     <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>JSP Page</title>
     </head>

     <body>
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
    <%

    Connection c1 = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    c1 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher","root", "abcde");
        {
         System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
         System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
         System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

         st = (Statement) c1.createStatement();
         System.out.println("Statement Created Successfully");
         {
         System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");
         }
         if (c1!= null) {
        System. out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
         } else {
         System.out.println("We should never get here.");
            }}
          %>
```

---

**index.jsp**

```
     <form  action="register.jsp" autocomplete="on"> 
     <h1> Sign up </h1> 
     <p> 
     <label for="firstnamesignup" class="fname" data-icon="u">First Name:</label>
     <input id="firstnamesignup" name="first" required="required" type="text" placeholder="First" />
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="lastnamesignup" class="lname" data-icon="u">Last Name:</label>
     <input id="lastnamesignup" name="last" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Last" />
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Username:</label>
     <input id="usernamesignup" name="user" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Password:</label>
     <input id="passwordsignup" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="password" data-icon="p">Confirm Password:</label>
     <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="confirmpass" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" >Email:</label>
     <input id="emailsignup" name="email" required="required" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com"/> 
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label>Date of Birth:</label>
     <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
     <option value="na">Month</option>
     <option value="1">January</option>
     <option value="2">February</option>
     <option value="3">March</option>
     <option value="4">April</option>
     <option value="5">May</option>
     <option value="6">June</option>
     <option value="7">July</option>
     <option value="8">August</option>
     <option value="9">September</option> 
     <option value="10">October</option>
     <option value="11">November</option>
     <option value="12">December</option>
     </select>
     <select name="day" id="day">
     <option value="na">Day</option>
     </select>
     <select name="year" id="year">
     <option value="na">Year</option>
     </select>
     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     function changeDate(i){
     var e = document.getElementById('day');
     while(e.length>0)
     e.remove(e.length-1);
     var j=-1;
     if(i=="na")
     k=0;
     else if(i==2)
     k=28;
     else if(i==4||i==6||i==9||i==11)
     k=30;
     else
     k=31;
     while(j++<k){
     var s=document.createElement('option');
     var e=document.getElementById('day');
     if(j==0){
     s.text="Day";
     s.value="na";
     try{
     e.add(s,null);}
     catch(ex){
     e.add(s);}}
     else{
     s.text=j;
     s.value=j;
     try{
     e.add(s,null);}
     catch(ex){
     e.add(s);}}}}
     y = 1998;
     while (y-->1908){
     var s = document.createElement('option');
     var e = document.getElementById('year');
     s.text=y;
     s.value=y;
     try{
     e.add(s,null);}
     catch(ex){
     e.add(s);}}
     </script> 
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label>Gender:</label>
     <select name="Gender">
     <option value="male">Male</option>
     <option value="female">Female</option>
     </select>
     </p>
     <p class="signin button"> 
     <input type="submit" value="Register"/> 
     </p>
     </form>
```

---

**error**

```
     HTTP Status 500 -
     type Exception report
     message
     description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
     exception
     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /teach.jsp:35
     32:             
     33:String Sql="insert into teacher2(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) values('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";
      34:             
      35:             rs=st.executeQuery(Sql);   
      38:         %>
```

**Stacktrace:**

`org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:451)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)`

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: i know but i want to execute my register.jsp page in any condition.

Comment: It seems the problem is "db conn.jsp" file is not included properly.
Can you try 1)avoiding space in filename (db conn.jsp) 2)change .jsp into .jspf

Comment: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /teach.jsp(9,0) File "/dbconn.jspf" not found` after that  Sundararaj Govindasamy

Comment: i think here is the error  `rs=st.executeQuery(Sql);`